# Print the last occurrences of duplicate line only

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I've got stdout from a command for which I'd like to strip duplicates in reverse order.

That is, I'd like the duplicate lines stripped from the beginning not from the end.  For example, to strip from the end I might use the classic technique with `awk`:

```
awk '!a[$0]++'
```

While brilliant, it strips the wrong lines:

```
$ printf 'one\nfour\ntwo\nthree\nfour\n' | awk '!a[$0]++'
one
four
two
three
```

I'd like the last occurrence of `four` printing *i.e.*

```
$ printf 'one\nfour\ntwo\nthree\nfour\n' | <script>
one
two
three
four
```

How do I do this?  Is there a simple way with a one-liner in shell?

Comment: NB: perl was invented to improve on using awk+sed+shell+...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your example to generate input for testing:

```
printf 'one\nfour\ntwo\nthree\nfour\n'
```

The easiest way to handle this is simply to reverse your data, twice.  The following works in BSD and OS X:

```
command | tail -r | awk '!a[$0]++' | tail -r
```

But the `-r` option isn't universal.  If you're on Linux, you can generate the same effect with the `tac` command (opposite of `cat`) which is part of coreutils:

```
command | tac | awk '!a[$0]++' | tac
```

If neither of these works (i.e. you're on HP/UX or older Solaris, etc), you may be able to reverse things using `sed`:

```
command | sed '1!G;h;$!d' | awk '!a[$0]++' | sed '1!G;h;$!d'
```

Of course, you could do this with perl as well:

```
command | perl -e 'print reverse <>' | awk '!a[$0]++' | perl -e 'print reverse <>'
```

But if perl is available on your system, you might as well simplify the pipe and skip awk entirely:

```
command | perl -e '$a{$_}++ or print for reverse <>'
```

I've never really liked perl, though, and I *do* like doing things in shell.  If you're in bash (version 4 or up), and you don't care much about performance, you can implement an array right in your shell:

```
mapfile -t a < <(command)
declare -A b;
for (( i=${#a[@]}-1 ; i>=0; i-- )); do ((b[${a[$i]}]++)) || echo "${a[$i]}"; done
```

No external tools required.  :-)

**UPDATE:**

Inspired (or perhaps challenged) by [sudo_O's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19258682/1072112), here's one more option that works in pure awk on BSD (i.e. doesn't require GNU awk):

```
command | awk '{a[NR]=$0;b[$0]=NR} END {for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) if(i==b[a[i]]) print a[i]}'
```

Note that this stores all input in memory *twice*, so it may be inappropriate for large datasets.

Comment: That seems like a lot of pipes.

Comment: +1 for original answer of `tail` and `rev`. `sed | awk | sed` and `perl | awk | perl` is never a good option IMHO however.

Comment: @Graham, True.  Updated answer with additional options.  :)  Note that anything that *reads your input into an array in memory* will use a lot of memory when reversing big files.

Comment: @sudo_O - I agree completely, those were just a bridge to the final perl-only solution. :)

Comment: +1 for `tac | awk '!a[$0]++' | tac`. Personally, I wouldn't even consider any of the others.

Comment: The bash and awk solutions are just ... twisted.

Answer (score 2):

In practice I would use **[ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19258523/1066031)** technique *(`rev`)* but here is a single `GNU awk` script to print the last occurrences:

```
command | awk '{a[$0]=NR;b[NR]=$0}END{n=asort(a);for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print b[a[i]]}'
one
two
three
four
```

Comment: **+1** ... Kudos.  I was trying to figure out how to do this in awk, and it made my brain hurt.  :-)